# Error Show: ScrollBar to zoom in Googlemap APi

Tags: google-maps-api-3, scrollbar, zooming

Iam begin use GoogleMap Api, when show map: ScrollBar to zoom (and icon to streetview ) show not properly: it's very small

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/EkfoDzVR7n2upzkc59l6c9YVSw1oO7M1R8_2D5QixZiuGEFKEjKXNRe1t4MDGwj9DkeAj9iCyjE=w1283-h539

How to fix ?
Thank all

p/s: My English is very bad :(((

Comment: Error403: Your client does not have permission to get URL....

Comment: @Dr.Molle can you explain detail ? how to fix ?? thank.

Comment: We are not able to see the linked page, because the access is restricted. Make it public accessible.

Comment: We can't access your link. Most likely a CSS issue if it looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

You have to had this css property :

```
#carte img { max-width:none !important; }
```

Where "#carte" is your map's ID